# IE problem with li's showing up as inline rather than inline block (i think)

Tags: html, internet-explorer

http://studiobambini.com/articles/Lifestyle/bambini-future

Hover over the Fashion menu item and you will see what the issue is in IE. In chrome and firefox this works fine.

Basically what I believe is happening is some property or other is inheriting a property in IE but not in chrome. I've tried text align, i've tried setting the widths, and changing the background colours.

It almost seems like there's other elements that have a background and are covering the rest of the elements. I'm at a total loss as to what to try next.

Can I get any suggestions on items to try to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I ie the padding is not taking corectly for the 'a' of the menu in chromeand FF its taking from line 222 `#menu ul li ul li:last-child a, #menu ul li ul li a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    color: #8A8C8E;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 60px;
    width: 155px;
}`

Comment: Sir! that was the fix. Upgrade that comment to an answer so I may shower it with points

Comment: ok.. fine..is that you are using any other CSS for IE only, where it coming frm?

Comment: i don't have any ie only css, well was just playing around with it so that's why you may have seen it befire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE the padding is not taking correctly for the 'a' of the menu in chrome and FF its taking from line 222

```
#menu ul li ul li:last-child a,
#menu ul li ul li a {
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
 color: #8A8C8E; font-size: 13px;
 height: 30px;
 margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 60px;
 width: 155px; 
}
```